# Subwoofer output on TPA3110D2 chip

Tags: audio, power-amplifier

I was looking for an amplifier to make a sound system with, and came across this amplifier that comes with a 30W subwoofer output: [https://www.amazon.com/SZHFJCTH-Amplifier-Subwoofer-amplifiers-Solicitation/dp/B09ZFB6XHY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09ZFB6XHY)

I noticed it was using the TPA3110D2 chip. However, when looking at the pinout, it did not seem to have a pin dedicated to driving subwoofers.

Does anybody know how these manufacturers are getting 30W subwoofer output (and how I could replicate it in a circut)?

Answer (score 0):

The 3rd photo shows screw terminals for Subwoofer, Left and Right.
The Amazon 2.1 amplifier module uses **two** TPA3110 stereo amplifier ICs.
The subwoofer channel uses both of its stereo channels in parallel as shown in the datasheet (page 24) of the TPA3110.
Note that none of the speaker terminals are grounded.

Comment: Yes, but arent subwoofers unable to do sounds over 250hz? Are they using a low-pass filter to ignore all frequencies above 250hz?

Comment: The seller of the amplifier says there is a dual opamps lowpass filter that has no specs. A lowpass filter has a slope of the levels at various frequencies. The slope might be 12dB per octave which is 1/4 the level for each doubling of the frequency. When the level is -40dB (1/100th) it is still heard. When the level is -60dB (1/1000th) then it is very low.